# Turning single column data into a grid

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data:

[image]

The grid of blue cells are created by using these formulas manually in column C:

```
C1: TRANSPOSE(A1:A5)
C2: TRANSPOSE(A6:A10)
C3: TRANSPOSE(A11:A15)
C4: TRANSPOSE(A16:A20)
C5: TRANSPOSE(A21:A25)
C6: TRANSPOSE(A26:A30)
```

I'm trying to create one formula using `Arrayformula` in `C1` that will automatically create the blue grid with *N* columns - currently *N* being 5.

Tried multiple ways to generate the range to transpose but not getting anywhere.

Any pointers on how to go about this?

**Note:** This could be done using app script, but I do not want to go that route and stick with `Arrayformula` or whatever that works.

Comment: Please share a link to a spreadsheet that *realistically* depicts your issue. I could write a solution to what you've posted using only what you've posted; but it likely won't work against your real-world data, which we can't guess at. For instance, your alphabet source starts in Row 1. I would approach a formula a certain way, since element 1 of the grid will match Row 1, etc. But does your real data *actually* start in Row 1? If not, then my proposed formula won't work. Formulas are built on details. Help us help you and share a link to *realistic* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my important comment to your original post. That said, given *only and exactly* what you show in your post, this would achieve your goal:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/5),5),FILTER({SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A)),A:A},A:A<>""),2,FALSE)))`

Change the number of columns in the grid by changing both instances of 5 to some other number (the same number for each instance).

Comment: Thanks for this. The actual sheet looks form like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJlto.png. The important things being that the formula will always be in the same row where column A starts. However the non-empty row for column A can start from any row.

Comment: The formula I shared will work. Just change every instance of `A:A` to `A5:A`. Please mark my answer post as "Best Answer." This will allows the volunteer contributor community to see from the main listings page which issues have already been resolved; and it will help future site visitors most quickly find this answer.

Comment: after experimenting with this, i found that if there is a lot of data and a lot (2000+) of rows on the sheet, then the formula can fail to give results, so it is best to lock the length of the range. and use the same range and sheet reference for all the `A:A`, except for the `ROWS(A:A)` which should not have a sheet reference, just make the size the same.

Comment: Each situation is different, @MrShane. This is a point I tried to make clear. In the absence of a realistic data set or additional information, the formula that I proposed here was written *solely and only* around the data that the OP posted. If you yourself have a different need, I invite you to share a new post being as specific as possible about the details (if you weren't able to modify this solution to *your* specific details.

Comment: @ErikTyler, originally, the amount of data i had was calculating for ages and wouldnt give result, so heres example how i was able to adapt your formula by adding in the row range, like this: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A1000)/5),5),FILTER({SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A1000)),Sheet1!A2:A1000},Sheet1!A2:A1000<>""),2,FALSE)))`. So not enough for an answer on its own as yours is great solution (hence my accepting yours as the answer).